# Entity Framework Fluent API Multiplicity constraint violated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I've been stumped by the following problem all day now and I've tried numerous suggestions but to no avail.

Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'GPContract_GPCustomer_Target' of the relationship 'Kezber.CSP.DAL.GPContract_GPCustomer' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Here is my database setup:

[image]

Now this means that a GPCustomer can have 0 to many GPContracts since CUSTNMBR is a nullable FK. (Don't ask about the naming convention, I inherited like this).

Here is my entity framework Fluent API setup and classes:

```
public class GPCustomer
{
    [Key]        
    public string CUSTNMBR { get; set; }
    public string GPCustomerName { get; set; }        
    public string BillToAddress { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string LocationCode { get; set; }
    public string MEContractClass { get; set; }
    public string PaymentTerms { get; set; }
    public string SalesPerson { get; set; }
    public string ShipToAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GPContract> Contracts { get; set; }        

    public GPCustomer()
    {
        Contracts = new HashSet<GPContract>();
    }
}

public class GPContract
{
    [Key]
    public string ME_Contract_Number { get; set; }
    public string CUSTNMBR { get; set; }   

    public virtual GPCustomer GPCustomer { get; set; }        
}

    public GPCustomerMap()
    {            
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(m => m.CUSTNMBR);            

        // Properties            
        Property(m => m.CUSTNMBR).HasMaxLength(15);
        Property(m => m.GPCustomerName).HasMaxLength(65);
        Property(m => m.BillToAddress).HasMaxLength(15);
        Property(m => m.Currency).HasMaxLength(15);
        Property(m => m.LocationCode).HasMaxLength(11);
        Property(m => m.MEContractClass).HasMaxLength(15);
        Property(m => m.PaymentTerms).HasMaxLength(21);
        Property(m => m.SalesPerson).HasMaxLength(15);
        Property(m => m.ShipToAddress).HasMaxLength(15);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("GPCustomers");            
        Property(m => m.CUSTNMBR).HasColumnName("CUSTNMBR");
        Property(m => m.GPCustomerName).HasColumnName("GPCustomerName");
        Property(m => m.BillToAddress).HasColumnName("BillToAddress");
        Property(m => m.Currency).HasColumnName("Currency");
        Property(m => m.LocationCode).HasColumnName("LocationCode");
        Property(m => m.MEContractClass).HasColumnName("MEContractClass");
        Property(m => m.PaymentTerms).HasColumnName("PaymentTerms");
        Property(m => m.SalesPerson).HasColumnName("SalesPerson");
        Property(m => m.ShipToAddress).HasColumnName("ShipToAddress");

        // Relationships               
    }

    public GPContractMap()
    {            
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(m => m.ME_Contract_Number);

        // Properties
        Property(m => m.ME_Contract_Number).HasMaxLength(21);
        Property(m => m.CUSTNMBR).HasMaxLength(15);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("GPContracts");            
        Property(m => m.ME_Contract_Number).HasColumnName("ME_Contract_Number");
        Property(m => m.CUSTNMBR).HasColumnName("CUSTNMBR");

        // Relationships  
        HasRequired(m => m.GPCustomer);
    }

    private IQueryable<GPCustomer> GetList()
    {
        var source = new EfRepository<GPCustomer>(_context).GetList();

        if (_withContracts)
            source = QueryableExtensions.Include(source, i => i.Contracts);

        return source;
    }
```

So how do I set this up properly? I've tried many different mapping configurations for the relationships but nothing works, I keep getting the multiplicity constraint violation error when I update a GPCustomer that has a GPContract when I do this:

```
new EfRepository<GPCustomer>(_context).Update(customer);
```

which in reality is this:

```
DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Thanks!

Update 1:

If I add the following relationship (FK) in GPContractMap:

```
HasRequired(m => m.GPCustomer).WithMany(m => m.Contracts).HasForeignKey(m => m.CUSTNMBR);
```

When I update now a GPCustomer, the entry in the GPContracts table is now updated but the CUSTNMBR gets set to null.

Comment: I'm not seeing your foreign key setup

Comment: I tried HasMany(p => p.Childs).WithRequired(p => p.Parent).Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentId")); and many other things, removed it since the above code works for reading the entities.

Comment: With a nullable foreign key it should be `HasOptional(m => m.GPCustomer)....`. Is this code-first with migrations? And what do you mean by your last sentence? Also, when/where do you get this exception?

Comment: I added HasOptional(m => m.GPCustomer).WithMany(m => m.Contracts).HasForeignKey(m => m.CUSTNMBR); This is using Fluent API and no migrations, the error happens on the update as stated above.